# streamKafkaP with projectionFn + Kafka timestamp.extractor

Tags: apache-kafka, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I'm using a [projectionFn](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/blob/v0.5.1/hazelcast-jet-kafka/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/jet/core/processor/KafkaProcessors.java#L47) for the KafkaSource in order to parse a JSON string as my kafka message value.

```
Vertex kafkaSource = dag.newVertex("kafkaSource", streamKafkaP(properties, decodeKafkaMessage, topic));
```

But, the kafka documentation defines a message/record as:

```
- a key,
- a value,
- and a timestamp. (built-in timestamp)
```

Via projectionFn, looks like that I'm only able to access the **key** and the **value** from each message. How could I have access to the **timestamp** value via **Kafka timestamp.extractor** ?

Comment: Only in Kafka 0.10+, is that the definition of a Kafka record. And in 1.0+, there's also a header map https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-82+-+Add+Record+Headers

Comment: hi @cricket_007. I'm using Kafka 0.10+. My questions is how to get the message timestamp when defining my projectionFn in the Jet application.

Comment: Well, `writeKafkaP` never passes a timestamp itself, so it would not surprise me if there's nowhere it's extracted. But if you have a Record object at any point, you can get the timestamp yourself

Comment: And in this class, ConsumerRecord timestamp method is never called. https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/blob/v0.5.1/hazelcast-jet-kafka/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/jet/impl/connector/kafka/StreamKafkaP.java

Comment: @KleysonRios This is not currently possible as you have found out. I have created an issue and we will fix this in 0.6: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/issues/721